# SQLAlchemy with dataclass default not populating postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using `dataclasses` combined with the SQLAlchemy classical mapping paradigm.  When I define a `dataclass` combined with default values for the `int` and `str` fields SQLAlchemy does not populate the `int` and `str`s, but it does populate the `List` and `datetime` fields.  For example the following code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, ARRAY, TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, mapper

metadata = MetaData()
person_table = \
    Table('people', metadata,
          Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
          Column('name', String(255)),
          Column('age', Integer),
          Column('hobbies', ARRAY(String)),
          Column('birthday', TIMESTAMP)
          )

@dataclass
class Person:
    id: int = None
    name: str = ''
    age: int = 0
    hobbies: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    birthday: datetime = field(default_factory=datetime)

mapper(Person, person_table)

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres@localhost:32771/test', echo=True)
metadata.create_all(engine)

session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
person = Person(id=None, name='Robby', age=33, hobbies=['golf', 'hiking'], birthday=datetime(1985, 7, 25))
session.add(person)
session.commit()
```

This correctly populates the `person` object in memory, but the `commit` operation produces the following data in postgres (the `name` and `age` columns are `null`):

```
 id | name | age |    hobbies    |      birthday       
----+------+-----+---------------+---------------------
  1 |      |     | {golf,hiking} | 1985-07-25 00:00:00
```

If I change the `Person` class to remove the default values from `name` and `age` then the data is populated correctly in postgres:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    id: int = None
    name: str
    age: int
    hobbies: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    birthday: datetime = field(default_factory=datetime)
```

Note, I have verified that when the `person` object is created in the "no-default" version of the class that the `name` and `age` fields are populated correctly in memory.

How do I use SQLAlchemy classical mappings in conjunction with dataclasses with default values?

(Python 3.6, SQLAlchemy 1.2.16, PostgreSQL 11.2)

Comment: Isn't this due to the difference between `default` and `server_default`?

Comment: i have a similar issue, can anyone suggest please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67185813/sqlalchemy-with-dataclass-and-postgres-db-not-working-with-foreign-key-how-do-i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `''` and `0` are respectively default returned values of `str()` and `int()` functions, you could use the following code to insert thoses defaults:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    id: int = None
    name: str = field(default_factory=str)
    age: int = field(default_factory=int)
    hobbies: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    birthday: datetime = field(default_factory=datetime)
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, using `default` parameter of `field()` function does not work as we could expect (could be a bug of the `dataclasses` backport or a misunterstanding...). But you still can use the `default_factory` to specify values differents from `''` and `0` using `lambda`:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    id: int = None
    name: str = field(default_factory=lambda: 'john doe')
    age: int = field(default_factory=lambda: 77)
    hobbies: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    birthday: datetime = field(default_factory=datetime)
```

Comment: this works if I declare `name: str = field(default_factory=str)` but not when `name: str = field(default=20)`.  I would be satisfied if the more advanced uses of fields were not handled, but the default value is pretty essential.

Comment: @robbymurphy: I updated the the answer with a tested solution which works for default values other than `''` and `0` using `default_factory` and `lambda`

Comment: It doesn't explain why `default='john doe'` doesn't work, but to be fair it answers my original question.  I'll give this a try and mark as answer if it works.

Comment: At least one reason why `default=` does not work is that dataclasses sets the default as a class attribute, and SQLA classical mapping does not setup instrumentation over existing class attributes.

Comment: The sad thing is: One uses classical mapping to avoid invasive changes to current codebase (not inheriting from Base). But now, you need to change your codebase to make it work with defaults. (I know that it's still invasive, as the instrumentation attaches the table and other meta information to the class).

Answer (score 1):

Mapping changes the class that you map. So dataclass attributes are overwritten by Columns from the table and properties describes in mapping. You will see more issues when you declare

> @dataclass(frozen=True)

You should use default values in Column declaration and maybe the declared model fits better for you, it's similar to dataclass.

If you want to separate infrastructure/DB from your domain code then you need another approach. For this, I suggest do treat your dataclass as an interface for DB Model. So DB Model will implement the behavior described by your DTO. But to make it work you will need a repository that can handle this.
I describe a similar case in this blogpost: [4 ways of mapping Value Object in SQLAlchemy](https://lukeonpython.blog/2020/11/4-ways-of-mapping-value-object-in-sqlalchemy/)