# SQLAlchemy CRUD operation is inconsistent with or without outcome assignment

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an app where I want the user to be able to bookmark/un-bookmark a blog, but upon un-bookmarking, I don't want to remove that bookmark record. So I have an `is_bookmarked` property on my Bookmark model to determine whether a bookmark is active/inactive.

In my test file, I have

```py
def test_unbookmark_a_blog_do_assign(session):
    blog = create_blog(session)

    bookmark = toggle_bookmark(session, blog_id=blog.id)
    assert len(blog.bookmarks) == 1

    toggle_bookmark(session, blog_id=blog.id)
    assert len(blog.bookmarks) == 0
```

This test passes. However, the following won't. (**Only difference is I do not assign a variable for the `toggle_bookmark`'s outcome.**)

```py
def test_unbookmark_a_blog_no_assign(session):
    blog = create_blog(session)

    toggle_bookmark(session, blog_id=blog.id)
    assert len(blog.bookmarks) == 1

    toggle_bookmark(session, blog_id=blog.id)
    assert len(blog.bookmarks) == 0
```

It fails at the second assertion `assert len(blog.bookmarks) == 0`. Reason is that `blog._bookmarks[0].is_bookmarked` does not get updated outside `toggle_bookmark` function and is still `True`, making it available in `blog.bookmarks`. (Definition attached below)

For context, I am using classic mapping:

```py
@dataclass
class Bookmark:
    is_bookmarked: bool = True
    blog_id: Optional[int] = None

@dataclass
class Blog:
    _bookmarks: List[Bookmark] = field(default_factory=list)

    def add_bookmark(self, bookmark):
        self._bookmarks.append(bookmark)

    @property
    def bookmarks(self):
        return [bookmark for bookmark in self._bookmarks if bookmark.is_bookmarked]

...

blog_table = Table(
    "blog",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, index=True))

bookmark_table = Table(
    "bookmark",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, index=True),
    Column("is_bookmarked", Boolean, default=True),
    Column("blog_id", ForeignKey("blog.id"), nullable=True),
)

...

mapper(
        Blog,
        blog_table,
        properties={
            "_bookmarks": relationship(Bookmark, back_populates="blog"),
            },
        )

mapper(
        Bookmark,
        bookmark_table,
        properties={
            "blog": relationship(Blog, back_populates="_bookmarks"),
            },
        )
```

The `toggle_bookmark` function:

```py
def toggle_bookmark(db_session, *, blog_id):
    blog = db_session.query(Blog).get(blog_id)
    bookmark = db_session.query(Bookmark).filter(
        Bookmark.blog_id == blog_id
    ).one_or_none()

    if bookmark is None:
        bookmark = Bookmark()
        blog.add_bookmark(bookmark)
        db_session.add(blog)
        db_session.commit()
        return bookmark

    bookmark.is_bookmarked = not bookmark.is_bookmarked
    db_session.add(bookmark)
    db_session.commit()
    return bookmark
```

I am really confused... My gut tells me that it has something to do when the query gets evaluated but I haven't managed to find any evidence to support it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

A full example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional, List
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, Boolean, ForeignKey)
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, relationship, sessionmaker

@dataclass
class Bookmark:
    is_bookmarked: bool = True
    blog_id: Optional[int] = None

@dataclass
class Blog:
    _bookmarks: List[Bookmark] = field(default_factory=list)

    def add_bookmark(self, bookmark):
        self._bookmarks.append(bookmark)

    @property
    def bookmarks(self):
        return [bookmark for bookmark in self._bookmarks if bookmark.is_bookmarked]

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///")
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

blog_table = Table(
    "blog",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, index=True))

bookmark_table = Table(
    "bookmark",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, index=True),
    Column("is_bookmarked", Boolean, default=True),
    Column("blog_id", ForeignKey("blog.id"), nullable=True),
)

metadata.create_all()

mapper(
        Blog,
        blog_table,
        properties={
            "_bookmarks": relationship(Bookmark, back_populates="blog"),
            },
        )

mapper(
        Bookmark,
        bookmark_table,
        properties={
            "blog": relationship(Blog, back_populates="_bookmarks"),
            },
        )

def toggle_bookmark(db_session, *, blog_id):
    blog = db_session.query(Blog).get(blog_id)
    bookmark = db_session.query(Bookmark).filter(
        Bookmark.blog_id == blog_id
    ).one_or_none()

    if bookmark is None:
        bookmark = Bookmark()
        blog.add_bookmark(bookmark)
        db_session.add(blog)
        db_session.commit()
        return bookmark

    bookmark.is_bookmarked = not bookmark.is_bookmarked
    db_session.add(bookmark)
    db_session.commit()
    return bookmark

def create_blog(session):
    blog = Blog()
    session.add(blog)
    session.commit()
    return blog

def test_unbookmark_a_blog_do_assign(session):
    blog = create_blog(session)

    bookmark = toggle_bookmark(session, blog_id=blog.id)
    assert len(blog.bookmarks) == 1

    toggle_bookmark(session, blog_id=blog.id)
    assert len(blog.bookmarks) == 0

def test_unbookmark_a_blog_no_assign(session):
    blog = create_blog(session)

    toggle_bookmark(session, blog_id=blog.id)
    assert len(blog.bookmarks) == 1

    toggle_bookmark(session, blog_id=blog.id)
    assert len(blog.bookmarks) == 0

Session = sessionmaker()

test_unbookmark_a_blog_do_assign(Session())
test_unbookmark_a_blog_no_assign(Session())
```

Comment: Ok, I think I found something: [joinedload & lazy-loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html?highlight=joinedload#lazy-loading)

Comment: If I access `blog._bookmarks` by adding `bookmarks = blog.bookmarks` before the second `crud.blog.toggle_bookmark`, the test will pass. However, I still get the same error after setting `"_bookmarks": relationship(Bookmark, back_populates="blog", lazy="joined"),` in `Blog`'s mapping configuration.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Mapping code added. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: My guess is you need to return bookmark because it goes out of scope and gets garbage collected when your crud function returns, but if you assign it to a variable it increments the reference count.  Their documentation has some examples on how you can work with and inspect session state to troubleshoot the issue https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_state_management.html

Comment: @LucasScott Thanks for the advice! That sounds possible. I will try and see if I can get something useful by inspecting the session.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks for the advice. I will try to do so after finishing work at hand.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I have created a minimal example on [Github here](https://github.com/HymanZHAN/sqlalchemy_demo). It'd be very appreciated if you could take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem is this:

```
class Bookmark:
    is_bookmarked: bool = True  # <-- This here
```

Classical mapping does not install instrumentation over the existing class attribute, and so any changes to an instance's `is_bookmarked` are not persisted. From there it follows that without the assignment the test reads the state from the database, where it holds its default value `True`. With the assignment the instance is kept around in the scope of the test and so in the `Session`, and the later queries return the existing modified instance.

You would run into similar issues with SQLAlchemy, and dataclasses and `field()`, if using `default=`:

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass, field
>>> @dataclass
... class C:
...  f: bool = field(default=True)
... 
>>> C.f
True
```

A solution to get over the situation is to use a `field()` with `default_factory=` for `is_bookmarked` as well:

```
@dataclass
class Bookmark:
    is_bookmarked: bool = field(default_factory=lambda: True)
    ...
```

since in recent enough Python the `field()` is then not visible in the class as an attribute, and mapping can install instrumentation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I must have been very careless here. I encountered similar problems for other types of fields like `list` and  `integer` before with something like `field(default=[])` or `field(default=0)`. I really need to do a thorough check on other dataclass models in case I got away with other careless default assignments.

Comment: Good read on the subject: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5027

Comment: Many thanks! I'd like to share another SO question from which I first learned about this problem with those who are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577165/sqlalchemy-with-dataclass-default-not-populating-postgres-database. But I guess you already knew about it. :)